# Add NTFS access to files with subfolders from CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I try to add NTFS access to the shortcuts.
I have the csv file that contains:

> ```
> Name,AD
> Steps Recorder,Group_312312
> Snipping Tool,Group_545345
> ```

```
$FolderPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\"
$file = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\Group.csv"
$groups = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv
 foreach ($group in $groups){ 
    Add-NTFSAccess -Path (Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath ($group.Name+".lnk")) `
                   -Account $group.AD `
                   -AccessRights ReadAndExecute `
    }
```

I have a lot of subfolders with *.lnk files in $FolderPath. But in this way, the scripts find only in $FolderPath without subfolders. How can I change the script to find all *.lnk files include subfolders?

```
For example:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\My_programs\OneDrive.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, I think you need a different approach, where you get a collection of *.lnk files recursively and filter to get only those which have a `BaseName` property that can be found in the CSV.

Next, use `Group-Object` to group (make sub-collections) of these FileInfo objects, based on their BaseName.

According to [the docs](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cmdlets/Add-NTFSAccess/), the `Path` parameter on the `Add-NTFSAccess` cmdlet can take an array of paths (FullName properties) and these can be piped through to it, so we can send each subcollection all at once:

```
$FolderPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories"
$file       = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\Group.csv"
$groups     = Import-Csv -Path $file

# get a list of *.lnk FileIfo objects where the file's BaseName can be found in the
# CSV column 'Name'. Group these files on their BaseName properties
$linkfiles  = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter '*.lnk' -File -Recurse -Force |
              Where-Object { $groups.Name -contains $_.BaseName } |
              Group-Object BaseName

# iterate through the grouped *.lnk files
$linkfiles | ForEach-Object {
    $baseName = $_.Name  # the name of the Group is the BaseName of the files in it
    $adGroup = ($groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $baseName }).AD
    # pipe all items in the group through to the Add-NTFSAccess cmdlet
    # see parameter Path at https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cmdlets/Add-NTFSAccess/
    $_.Group | Add-NTFSAccess -Account $adGroup -AccessRights ReadAndExecute
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
# this is where the output 'log' csv file goes
$outputFile = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\GroupReport.csv"

# get a list of *.lnk FileIfo objects where the file's BaseName can be found in the
# CSV column 'Name'. Group these files on their BaseName properties
$linkfiles  = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter '*.lnk' -File -Recurse -Force |
              Where-Object { $groups.Name -contains $_.BaseName } |
              Group-Object BaseName

# iterate through the grouped *.lnk files and add the group permission
# capture the results in a variable $log to output as CSV
$linkfiles | ForEach-Object {
    $baseName = $_.Name  # the name of the Group is the BaseName of the files in it
    $adGroup = ($groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $baseName }).AD

    # create a new access rule
    # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule
    $rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($adGroup, "ReadAndExecute", "Allow")

    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        # get the current ACL of the file
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName
        # add the new rule to the ACL
        $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
        $acl | Set-Acl $_.FullName
        # output for logging csv
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Group' = $adGroup
            'File'  = $_.FullName
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @юра But then you will stil need to match the basename property of the files to their corresponding AD groups from the CSV..

Comment: Hello @theo, how to modify the script using Get-Acl and Set-Acl built-in powershell commands? Without modules.

Comment: @юра I have added new code added code for using Get-Acl, Set-Acl instead of Add-NTFSAccess

Comment: I've had the error @Theo. Could you please take a look? Exception calling "SetAccessRule"  with "1" argument(s): "No flags can be set. Parameter name: inheritanceFlags" At line:24 char:9 + $acl.SetAccessRule($rule) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: @юра You may want to try the constructor with just 3 parameters:

`$rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($adGroup, "ReadAndExecute", "Allow")`

Comment: Thanks, it's working! @Theo One more question, how can I add logging to the script? To see which files got AD groups.

Comment: @юра I have added logging the results.

Comment: I've got an error @Theo. Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\adm\Desktop\script.ps1:62 char:8
+ $log | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: @юра Try the edited code. BTW, please do not keep adding new requirements after your original question has been answered..